# Doubt on the proof that two curves having the same orthogonal line everywhere have constant distance

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-explanation

There are two distinct parametrized curves $\alpha,\beta:I\subseteq R\rightarrow R^3$ with $\alpha$ parametrized by arc length (that is, $||\alpha'(s)||=1$$\forall s\in I)$, such that the curvature $\kappa(s)$ and the torsion $\tau(s)$ are non-zero in $I$ and such that, $\forall s\in I$, the line orthogonal to $\alpha$ passing through $\alpha(s)$ is the same as the line orthogonal to $\beta$ passing through $\beta(s)$. We have to prove that the distance between $\alpha(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ is a constant in $s$. We start by writing $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+r(s)N_{\alpha}(s)$ where $N_{\alpha}(s):I\subseteq R\rightarrow R^3$ is the normal vector to $\alpha$, which as we know $\alpha$ is P.A.L. is the same as $n_{\alpha}(s)$, the normal versor to $\alpha$; $r(s)$ is instead the norm of the distance between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $s$, or "how much we stretch $N_{\alpha}(s)$". Now, $\beta(s)=\alpha(s)+r(s)N_{\alpha}(s)\rightarrow \beta'(s)=\alpha'(s)+r'(s)N_{\alpha}(s)+r(s)N_{\alpha}'(s)$$\rightarrow T_{\beta}(s)=T_{\alpha}(s)+r'(s)N_{\alpha}(s)+r(s)N_{\alpha}'(s)$. But we know that $T_{\beta}$ and $N_{\alpha}$ are orthogonal $\forall s\in I$ (this is OK by a geometric viewpoint) so $<T_{\beta},N_{\alpha}>=0=r'$. So $r(s)$ is a constant and $\beta-\alpha$ is also a constant. I don't understand why $r'=<T_{\beta},N_{\alpha}>$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with an help of another person, I think I solved it. Considering the espression $T_{\beta}=T_{\alpha}+r'N_{\alpha}+rN'_{\alpha}$ and "dotting product" both sides by $N_{\alpha}$ we get $<T_{\beta},N_{\alpha}>=0+r'+0$. This is because of simple orthogonality between $T_{\alpha}$ and $N_{\alpha}$ and between $N'_{\alpha}$ and $N_{\alpha}$. So, $<T_{\beta},N_{\alpha}>=r'$ as desired.

Comment: Almost right. You won’t have $T_\beta$, but a scalar (function) multiple of it. Why?

Comment: Do you mean I won't get $r'$ but  a scalar multiple of $r'?$Honestly, I don't know why.

Comment: No, the curve $\beta$ is not arclength parametrized, so differentiating $\beta$ gives $\beta'(s) = \upsilon(s)T_\beta(s)$, where $\upsilon$ is the speed of the curve. It doesn't affect your dot product computation, however. But this is a standard first part to exercises on Bertrand mates, and this is an important point as one proceeds in those exercises.